# Best software to record voice synchronously with a video (i.e Dubbing)?

Tags: audio-recording

I want to dub some videos, i.e. transfer them to another language with my voice.

So, I need software to simply record my voice (one part after another), while showing me the original video and playing the original sound. This way I can have a sound file synchronized with the original video.

I have searched a lot and finally got to Corel Video Studio. But working with this software takes too much time. It needs to be clicked twice (no shortcut) to start recording, and going back and modifying is not so straightforward.

Is there any software more suitable for dubbing?

Answer (score 1):

Premeire Elements is (more) user friendly and not too hard to learn.   Also, Reaper has a built-in video player, as does Cubase and FL Studio.  Reaper and Premeire Elements are the best bet I think - both under $100.  Haven't used Cubase for this feature (but its probably the best of the lot based on what I've seen - and most expensive), and Fl Studio doesn't include the video player in their low-end editions, so it is $299 to get that feature (and there video player ain't that good).

Reaper might be difficult if you are unfamiliar with Digital Audio Software.

[Reaper](http://reaper.fm/)

[Cubase](http://steinberg.net)

[Fl Studio](http://www.image-line.com)

[Premeire Elements](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere-elements.html)

Answer (score 1):

Dubjoy is an advanced platform for translating and dubbing the videos.
offering video translation services as well as native speaker video voice-overs.

If you need to crowdsource a video, you can lease the platform, upload your videos and send translators/voice-talents to the public link.

[Here is an example video of dubbing workflow](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HC0E5UZ5Ikk)

It's as easy as it gets and it's all done from the Chrome web browser or an iPhone.

You can translate any YouTube video for free by using Dubjoy Chrome plug-in, but for MP4 video translation you need to lease the platform or order translation service.

Web interface can do only dry voice-overs for now, but iPhone has also back-audio volume control for every segment/sentence.

Dubjoy has already been used to dub KhanAcademy videos.

Disclosure: I'm a co-founder